# Error al instalr FIELDimageR en R

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de instalar la librería de FIELDimageR, sigo las recomendaciones que se indican en [Github](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/FIELDimageR#instal), he intentado instalarlo de las tres formas que se indica en la sección de instalar:

Forma 1

```
install.packages("FIELDimageR")
```

Forma 2

```
devtools::install_github("filipematias23/FIELDimageR.Extra")
```

Forma 3

```
setwd("I:/Datos_R/Demo/y2023L/ConteoPlantasR") # ~ is the path from where you saved the 
unzip("FIELDimageR-master.zip") 
file.rename("FIELDimageR-master", "FIELDimageR") 
shell("R CMD build FIELDimageR")
install.packages("FIELDimageR_0.3.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Sin embargo y ninguna me ha funcionado, me regresa el siguiente error

[image: Error al instalar]

La versión de R que estpy usando es la siguiente:
[image: Versión de R]

También he intentado con las recomendaciones en este enlace: [About the FIELDimageR category](https://community.opendronemap.org/t/about-the-fieldimager-category/4130/18), pero no ha funcionado nada.

Si alguien ya paso por este problema y lo puso solucionar y me pudiera ayudar porfavor, ya que no he encontrado la solución.

Comment: Instala primero las dependencias (EBImage, attempt, ... , spatialEco) y luego la librería FIELDimageR